# Cannot update order state and status programatically

Tags: magento2, order-status

This is my first attempt:

```
$orderId = 57;
    
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$order = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Sales\Model\Order')->load($orderId);
$order->setState(\Magento\Sales\Model\Order::STATE_PROCESSING, true);
$order->setStatus(\Magento\Sales\Model\Order::STATE_PROCESSING);
var_dump($order->getStatus()); // here i can see that it is processing
$order->save(); // if i put this in a try and catch, no exception is thrown
```

another attempt:

```
//using OrderRepositoryInterface
$order = $this->orderRepositoryInterface->get(57);
$order->setState('processing')->setStatus('processing');
$this->orderRepositoryInterface->save($order); // if i put this in a try and catch, no exception is thrown
```

Are they other approaches to try to change the order state and status ? Or am i doing something wrong with my attempts? since they are not working :(

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

For First code:

```
$order->setState(\Magento\Sales\Model\Order::STATE_PROCESSING, true);
```

is wrong as `\Magento\Sales\Model\Order::setState` only accept one parameter.

Second code is ok!.

Set status & state using code does not mean that your desire status & state will be set to Order for every `save()` method of order repository magento check order status at `\Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Handler\State::check` .So you have to check at this method why your state & status does not effect.